# diluted matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab I need to create a mesh (surf) of a function.
then I need to show the mesh contour lines.
in the end I need to show with arrows the contour lines direction.

I have this so far:

```
mesh(T); //T is the matrix [150x200] created by the function, this present me the mesh
contour(T);//this present me the contour lines
[px py]=gradient(T);//this for calculate gradient of T (px is[150x200] and also py)
contour(T), hold on, quiver(px,py), hold off //quiver is to make arrows
```

This work fine, I can see the contour lines but my problem is that the arrows are too crowded and what i'm seeing it not very clear.
I need to diluted px and py but I don't know how.
I don't know if it is something I need to do before the gradient function or after.
I need that px and py will stay on [150x200] and maybe replace some value in them to zero,
Thank you all!

Comment: Hello,
This is because I didn't get any good answer.
I do care and mark accept when the answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd "dilute" the arrow, (px,py) by sampling just a subset of them. For example:

```
N=25; % or usea different # of points if needed
range1=unique(round(linspace(1,size(T,1),N)));
range2=unique(round(linspace(1,size(T,1),N)));
[rx ry]=meshgrid(range1,range2);
quiver(rx,ry,px(range1,range2),py(range1,range2)); %, hold off
```

Comment: Hello natan, I have tried this before but it just make the px and py smaller. I can upload pictures if it will be more useful for understanding

Comment: This is what I have now:[link]( http://i49.tinypic.com/35n1s9z.jpg )
And this is what I have after making what you suggest:
[link]( http://i45.tinypic.com/1ilbib.jpg )
You can see it is just make px and py shrink.
What I want is something like this:
[link]( http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.gif )
In here you can see all arrows clearly.
I want that my plot will be as clear as in the example I bring.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Unfortunately it's not working.
The problem is that the ranges are different, because T is in size [150x200], so range1 is size 1x15 and range2 1x20, and quiver need them to be in the same size.

Comment: For Matrix size [NxN] it's good, but I need it to [MxN]
Thanks!